# console log value of object with Angular with parameters

Tags: angular

I'm trying to print a specific object value based on a parameter that a user is giving.

So let's say that I've got the following object:

```
rateCardSelected: any = {
    "carrierId": null,
    "carrierName": null,
    "customsClearanceCosts": null,
    "flegtSurcharge": null,
    "hsCodeCharge": null,
    "provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor": null,
    "prepaidCustomsDuty": null,
    "deliveryOrder": null,
    "inspectionCharges": null,
    "lsps20feet": null,
    "lsps40feet": null,
    "lastmileCtvrede": null,
    "ocmFee": null
  };
```

I fill this Object by using the a request:

```
  getCarrierCosts(selectedCarrier: any){
    let pathVariable = selectedCarrier;
    let url = 'http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + pathVariable;
    let rateCardSelected = this.http.get(url)
    rateCardSelected.subscribe((data) => this.rateCardSelected = data);
  }
```

So for so good. If I `console.log(this.rateCardSelected.carrierName);` it will gave me the carrier name as expected.

But my goal is that the user inputs what he wants to see. So I use this object to make the user select which value of the `rateCardSelected` object needs to be printed:

```
      nameDefinitions: any = [
        {id: 'customsClearanceCosts', name: 'Customs clearance costs'},
        {id: 'flegtSurcharge', name: 'Flegt surcharge'},
        {id: 'hsCodeCharge', name: 'HS-code surcharge'},
        {id: 'provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor', name: 'Provision pre-paid duties'},
etc...
      ]
```

When the user selects one of the above I can also make the selected value visible with the following:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Ledger</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedLedger" (selectionChange)="getLedger(selectedLedger)">
    <mat-option matInput required placeholder="label" *ngFor="let ledger of nameDefinitions" [value]="ledger.id">
      {{ledger.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


    getLedger(selectedLedger: any){
    console.log(selectedLedger);
  }
```

This will print flegtSurcharge for example.

Now the part where I struggle:

How can I make sure that it will print the value of flegtSurcharge from the selectedRateCard?
I've tried several things like:

```
  getLedger(selectedLedger: any){
    console.log(this.rateCardSelected.carrierName);
    console.log(selectedLedger);
    console.log(this.rateCardSelected.selectedLedger); //I want the value of the object right here!
  }
```

But with no success, instead "undefined" is printed.

Edit:
After I changed `console.log(this.rateCardSelected.selectedLedger);` to `console.log(this.rateCardSelected[selectedLedger]);` it still prints undefined.
After reading [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) from what I understand you should be able to use a dot notation as well right? Or is this different in Angular?

Any tips regarding my code are very welcome since I'm new to Angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it still shows "undefined" while I used console.log(this.rateCardSelected[selectedLedger.id]);

Comment: Then there's something wrong with `selectedLedger`, `selectedLedger.id`, `this`, `this.rateCardSelected`, or some combination thereof.

Comment: Solved the issue, see my answer below! You were right about the brackets. This in combination with a other change worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue with the following changes:

Changed parameter for function `getLedger()` from `any` to `string` like this:

```
getLedger(selectedLedger: string){
    console.log(this.rateCardSelected[selectedLedger]);
  }
```

When changed to a string the bracket notation as suggested by Heretic Monkey in the comments prints the value I wanted!